# Problems going back to original view?

Tags: 3d-view

can't go back to the original object view. Got stuck with this image and can't go back.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've stacked and collapsed several 3d windows. Press on the tiny "+" on the bottom right of your 3D window to get back the horizontal menu bar

[image]